# Not getting the id over username Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was trying to get the id of a username over the function:

```
var userID = client.users.cache.find((u) => u.tag === "Username").id
```

and get the error that `id` is undefined, I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to get a user by their username. you should use `cache.find((u) => u.username === "Username")`. Your code checks the string `Username` against `u.tag`, which will be something like `Username#1234` so it'll always return false.

Comment: Good to hear, remember to mark this as an answer :)